# Setting onClickListener to TableRow with TextViews

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow, android-tablelayout

Good day to all.

I have a `TableLayout` with three `TextView`s in each of its rows.  Is it still possible to add `OnClickListener` to the whole row?  I'd like to change the background colour of the selected row.    I've set an `OnClickListener` to the `TableRow` by doing the following, but the background colour doesn't change:

```
   for(int i =0; i < rowAmount; i++)
        {           
            TableRow tr= new TableRow(this);

            TextView rmNo;
            TextView s;
            TextView p;

            rmNo = new TextView(this);
            s = new TextView(this);
            p = new TextView(this);

            rmNo.setText("" + roomNumbers.get(i).toString());
            s.setText("" + statuses.get(i).toString());
            p.setText("" + priorities.get(i).toString());

            tr.addView(rmNo);
            tr.addView(s);
            tr.addView(p);      

            tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {                   
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    tr.setBackgroundColor(color.holo_blue_light);
                }
            });

            tblContent.addView(tr);
        }

    }
```

I am creating the TableRows and TextViews programmaticaly because their data is retrieved from a database.

This is the XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tblTitles">   
    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tblContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ob">


   </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any help / ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Already looked-up sources:

[How can I highlight the table row on click ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075356/how-can-i-highlight-the-table-row-on-click)

[How to change the background color of a TableRow when focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274343/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-tablerow-when-focused)

Comment: To the whole row or to each item in each row?

Comment: I need to change the colour of the whole row

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i tested it, and now it works just fine, try using

```
tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{                   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
    }
});
```

instead...

Comment: Hi malimo,  no it did not work.  I think I need to add a new XML defining the specific row's selected / focusable state, however I find it difficult to do so since I need to not just create a fixed number of table rows.

Comment: i tested it and it works just fine, i don't know what's wrong with your code. but if you want to draw something like a scrollable tablelayout i would suggest using a listview with a listadapter... putting a tablelayout into a scrollview is not best practise.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I managed to solve it following your example :)

Answer (score 1):

shape.xml

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#DDA0DD"
                android:endColor="#ffff00"
                android:angle="270" />
                       <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#ff00ff"
                android:startColor="#000fff"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#f0f0f0" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"

                android:color="#000000" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" 
                />
            <padding
                android:left="1dp"
                android:top="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</selector>
```

Then add

```
 tr.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape));
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use
`tr.setOnClickListener(this);`

instead of

```
tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {                   
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    tr.setBackgroundColor(color.holo_blue_light);
                }
            });
```

then

```
 @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
//you can set background color of 'v'
v.setBackgroundColor(color.holo_blue_light);
                }
```

Comment: have u set Id of tr?..then what happened when u click on tr?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on it.  Yes I have set an id for `tr`

Comment: debug it..check either 'v' is null or what!!

Answer (score 0):

Which bulid version are u using

try this

```
tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

or

```
tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Android 4.2.2 API lvl 17