# android tablelayout click row vs scrolling

Tags: java, android, scroll, tablelayout

I have a tablelayout where I need to select a row to do something with it latter. The problem is, when I scroll it selects a new row.
What I want it a way to not select a row when I only want to scroll

What I have for selecting a row is this:

```
...
TableRow tR = new TableRow(this);
 final TableLayout tabela = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
...
tR.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    tabela.getFocusedChild().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray1);//remove the old selected row
    arg0.requestFocus(); //add new one
    arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00")); //add new one
    return false;
}});
```

I think It' something to do with that "MotionEvent arg1" but I dont really know what to do with it.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075356/how-can-i-highlight-the-table-row-on-click/13950667#13950667

Answer (score 0):

I already found a way to solve this.
I only needed to add

```
if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
```

before the code